# Toggle a value bool and merge 2 arrays with filter, map or reduct

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, sorting, filter

I am trying to solve this question.

I have to inverse the value toggle when 2 arrays have a match on the id.

if isFavorite.id === data.id. E.g. 10 then I will toggle the bool in data "toggle". My goal is to merge the data fetched and the local storage if the user is not logged to create a new dataset.

This was my code

```
    useEffect(() => {
    let newLocalFav: any = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('FavoriteHistory') ?? '[]');
    var obj = {};

    var result = newLocalFav.reduce(
        (ids: any, thing: any) => {
            if (thing.value === true) {
                data = data.map((u: any) => (u.id !== thing.id ? u : 'aaa'));

                console.log('111', data);
            }
            return ids;
        },
        [data]
    );
```

isFavorite

```
{
"id": 10,
"timestamp": 1673937241640,
"value": true
}
```

data

```
[
{
    "id": 10,
    "created_at": "2023-01-09T01:52:25.617427+00:00",
    "address": "11-de-la-aaaa",
    "isActive": true,
    "images": {
        "data": {
            "1": "https://combo.staticflickr.com/ap/build/images/sohp/2020-top-25/A_Time_of_Change_Rachel_Brokaw.jpg",
            "2": "https://combo.staticflickr.com/ap/build/images/sohp/2020-top-25/If_Only_We_Could_Turn_Back_Time_Anna_Kwa.jpg"
        }
    },
    "price": 899000,
    "province": "qc",
    "city": "montreal",
    "borough": "ville-marie",
    "toggle": false
},
{
    "id": 5,
    "created_at": "2023-01-07T19:39:04.085424+00:00",
    "address": "1000-de-la-commune",
    "isActive": true,
    "images": {
        "data": {
            "1": "https://combo.staticflickr.com/ap/build/images/sohp/2020-top-25/A_Time_of_Change_Rachel_Brokaw.jpg",
            "2": "https://combo.staticflickr.com/ap/build/images/sohp/2020-top-25/If_Only_We_Could_Turn_Back_Time_Anna_Kwa.jpg"
        }
    },
    "price": 399000,
    "province": "qc",
    "city": "montreal",
    "borough": "ville-marie",
    "toggle": false
},
{
    "id": 3,
    "created_at": "2023-01-07T19:31:52.173764+00:00",
    "address": "1000-de-la-commune",
    "isActive": true,
    "images": {
        "data": {
            "1": "https://combo.staticflickr.com/ap/build/images/sohp/2020-top-25/A_Time_of_Change_Rachel_Brokaw.jpg",
            "2": "https://combo.staticflickr.com/ap/build/images/sohp/2020-top-25/If_Only_We_Could_Turn_Back_Time_Anna_Kwa.jpg"
        }
    },
    "price": 429000,
    "province": "qc",
    "city": "montreal",
    "borough": "ville-marie",
    "toggle": false
},
{
    "id": 8,
    "created_at": "2023-01-09T01:52:19.671964+00:00",
    "address": "111-de-la-tree",
    "isActive": true,
    "images": {
        "data": {
            "1": "https://combo.staticflickr.com/ap/build/images/sohp/2020-top-25/A_Time_of_Change_Rachel_Brokaw.jpg",
            "2": "https://combo.staticflickr.com/ap/build/images/sohp/2020-top-25/If_Only_We_Could_Turn_Back_Time_Anna_Kwa.jpg"
        }
    },
    "price": 510000,
    "province": "qc",
    "city": "montreal",
    "borough": "ville-marie",
    "toggle": false
}
```

]

The result should be toggle true for id: 10

```
    {
            "id": 10,
            "created_at": "2023-01-09T01:52:25.617427+00:00",
            "address": "11-de-la-aaaa",
            "isActive": true,
            "images": {
                "data": {
                    "1": "https://combo.staticflickr.com/ap/build/images/sohp/2020-top-25/A_Time_of_Change_Rachel_Brokaw.jpg",
                }
            },
            "price": 899000,
            "province": "qc",
            "city": "montreal",
            "borough": "ville-marie",
            "toggle": true
    },
{
    "id": 5,
    "created_at": "2023-01-07T19:39:04.085424+00:00",
    "address": "1000-de-la-commune",
    "isActive": true,
    "images": {
        "data": {
            "1": "https://combo.staticflickr.com/ap/build/images/sohp/2020-top-25/A_Time_of_Change_Rachel_Brokaw.jpg",
            "2": "https://combo.staticflickr.com/ap/build/images/sohp/2020-top-25/If_Only_We_Could_Turn_Back_Time_Anna_Kwa.jpg"
        }
    },
    "price": 399000,
    "province": "qc",
    "city": "montreal",
    "borough": "ville-marie",
    "toggle": false
}, ...
```

Comment: What's your question regarding this process?

Comment: I edited the question. In a nutshell, id 10 become toggle true after the merging of data and isFavorite

Comment: You're describing what your goal is, but there is no question that I can see. Does your code not do as intended? What's the actual result vs expected result?

Comment: I am not sure what approach to use. For now, the result array is only selecting the correct id and it changed the value to 'aaa'. 

The question is more what to do you instead of having 'aaa' I would get the data in the selected id that match put I toggle the value. E.g toggle: false to true

Comment: I think you may have to rebuild `u`, something like `{id: u.id, created_at:u.created_at,...,toggle:!u.toggle}`

Comment: I agree with that, but I could not find a way to push it the the rebuild array to the state.

Comment: Does it work for `u.id !== thing.id` when you are just returning `u`? Couldn't you replace `'aaa'` with `{id: u.id, created_at:u.created_at,...,toggle:!u.toggle}`?